# How can I reference WindowsBase in .Net5?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-5, bitmapframe

I am writing a .NET 5 class library that contains the following code:

```
public T[] ConvertToArray<T>(BitmapFrame frame, int samplesPerPixel) where T:struct
{
    var pixelWidth = frame.PixelWidth;
    var array = new T[pixelWidth  * frame.PixelHeight * samplesPerPixel];
    var stride = pixelWidth * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) *samplesPerPixel;
    frame.CopyPixels(array,stride,0);//this line prevents the code from compiling
    return array;
}
```

The line with `frame.CopyPixels` gives the following compilation error:

*CS7069 Reference to type 'Freezable' claims it is defined in 'WindowsBase', but it could not be found.
Module 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf385ad364e35' should be referenced*

[image]

I have been trying to add a reference to WindowsBase.dll from this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.8\WindowsBase.dll

But I get the following error:
*The reference is invalid or unsupported*

[image]

The weird part is that Freezable is listed under .NET 5 in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=net-5.0). Maybe the issue is that I am using WindowsBase.dll intended for .NET Framework, but I don't know where the .NET 5 version would be.

Any ideas how I can solve this and get my code to compile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution, but it makes the class library only compatible with windows applications.

In the project file change this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

To this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>True</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: In case you are not using net5, net6 but netstandard as target framework then this that helped me:
 <ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="WindowsBase">
   <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\WindowsBase.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
 </ItemGroup>